# Using CASE statement compare 3 conditions and have the statements executed

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apps

I have a requirement where in i'm supposed to take 3 dynamic values from the user and compare with the list of values present based on match of it I need to have conditions to be added to where clause using case statement.

```
select *
from   MY_DBSOURCE
WHERE  1=1
And LP_WHERE_REP = (CASE When :LP = 'LIFESHEILD' AND     :M = 'AP' AND :STATUS = 'Processed' THEN flag ='P' and Manual_FLAG = 'P' END)
AND     DATA_SOURCE IN ('LIFESHIELD') 
AND     DATE_CLOSED >= '15-JUL-2019'
AND     DATE_CLOSED <= '16-JUL-2019'
```

Comment: What is `LP_WHERE_REP`? Is that a column in the table? I feel like you are trying to go for something like `WHERE flag=CASE When :LP = 'LIFESHEILD' AND     :M = 'AP' AND :STATUS = 'Processed' THEN 'P END AND Manual_FLAG=CASE When :LP = 'LIFESHEILD' AND  :M = 'AP' AND :STATUS = 'Processed' THEN 'P' END AND DATA_SOURCE IN ('LIFESHIELD') AND DATE_CLOSED >= '15-JUL-2019' AND DATE_CLOSED <= '16-JUL-2019'`

Comment: Actually LP_WHERE_REP is my own variable which is incorrect.The thing which i'm looking is i want to compare these 3 conditions (:Lp = 'LIFESHEILD' AND  :M = 'AP' AND :P = 'Processed' ) which are dynamic values and if they are true then (flag ='P' and D_FLAG = 'P') this 2 condition based  select query data must come.

Answer (score 1):

`CASE` can be used in `WHERE`, but - syntax should be OK. Yours isn't.

Here's an example which shows *how* to do it (also, note that I used date literal for `date_closed`; you compared it to strings.

```
select *
from   my_dbsource
where  1=1
and lp_where_rep = case when :lp = 'LIFESHEILD' and :m = 'AP' and :status = 'Processed' then 'P' 
                        when manual_flag = 'P' then 'X'
                        else 'Y'
                   end
and     data_source in ('LIFESHIELD') 
and     date_closed >= date '2019-07-15'
and     date_closed <= date '2019-07-16'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a case in `WHERE` clause then you can use something like the following:

```
AND (CASE WHEN :LP = 'LIFESHEILD' AND :M = 'AP' AND :STATUS = 'Processed' THEN flag ELSE 'P' END) = 'P'
AND (CASE WHEN :LP = 'LIFESHEILD' AND :M = 'AP' AND :STATUS = 'Processed' THEN Manual_FLAG ELSE 'P' END) = 'P'
```

Cheers!!