# How to run a specific condition in where clause of select query based upon the input parameter?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, case, where-clause

I'm trying to have the condition of NVL work based on the parameter entered but it doesn't work with CASE statement.
I'm unable to get *NVL(hours,0)>0* condition run when my type parameter is entered as *'hours'*  and vice versa

```
SELECT * 
FROM   hours_tbl 
WHERE  1=1 
AND 
       CASE 
              WHEN :type ='Hours' THEN Nvl(hours,0)>0 
              WHEN :type ='Earnings' THEN Nvl(hours,0)=0 
              ELSE Nvl(hours,0)>=0
```

Comment: It's generally a bad idea to use `case` expressions in WHERE and ON clauses. Use AND/OR constructions instead.

Comment: A while back you asked a similar question and [somebody showed you the correct syntax for CASE in a WHERE clause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57040278/146325).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`CASE` does not do what you expect. It is meant to assign values, not to generate conditions. I think that you want  `OR`:

```
select * 
from hours_tbl 
where 
    1=1
    and (
        ( :type ='Hours' and nvl(hours, 0) > 0 )
        or ( :type ='Earnings' and nvl(hours, 0) =0 )
        or ( :type not in ('Hours','Earnings') and nvl(hours, 0) >= 0 )
    )
```

Note: as commneted by [@TonyAndrew](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18747/tony-andrews), if `:type` may be `NULL`, the last expression should be written:

```
( nvl(:type,'x') not in ('Hours','Earnings') and nvl(hours, 0) >= 0 )
```

Comment: Almost - the final `or` needs to be `(:type not in ('Hours','Earnings') and NVL(hours,0)>=0)` to match the CASE

Comment: Or perhaps even `(nvl(:type,'x') not in ('Hours','Earnings') and NVL(hours,0)>=0)` if :type can be null

Comment: @TonyAndrews: ah yes, you are right, thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CASE` statement if you make it to return a value which you can compare:

```
SELECT * 
FROM   hours_tbl 
WHERE  1=1 
AND    1=CASE 
           WHEN :type ='Hours' AND Nvl(hours,0)>0 THEN 1
           WHEN :type ='Earnings' AND Nvl(hours,0)=0 THEN 1 
           WHEN :type NOT IN ('Hours','Earnings') AND Nvl(hours,0)>=0 THEN 1
       END
```